# Jquery and Menu and logo

Tags: javascript, jquery

All,

I am trying to set up a website menu using [this Jqueryscript.net template.](https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Mobile-Multi-Level-Menu-jQuery-cookcodesmenu.html)

The instructions accompanying the template tell me to activate the script with

```
$(function() {
$('#menu').cookcodesmenu();
});
```

Later, there are customization options to link to my logo:

```
$('#menu').cookcodesmenu({
display: 1920, // From where mobile menu apears and desktop  menu gone
brand: 'LOGO', // Supports HTML
label: 'MENU', // <a href='https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/'>Menu</a> Label: // Supports HTML
});
```

I can't figure out how to follow these instructions. I have tried things like

```
script>
$(function() {
    $('#menu').cookcodesmenu({
        logo: '<a href="/images/BodyLogo.jpg"</a>'
    });
});
</script>
```

with no luck.

Frankly, I would much prefer to simply activate the menu while omitting the logo and coding in my site logo via html. But if that's not an option, I'd like to know not only how to call it from within this menu code, but also give directions within the script for the size of the logo. (as you would in html, width="25%," etc.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Added later:

Per your request, here's the html, but I don't think that's the problem, as I'll explain in a second.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>(website)/title>
<!--Menu-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
<link href="Menu/CSS/MenuStyles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"   
 type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Menu/CSS/Menu.css">
<script src="Menu/JS/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="Menu/JS/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Menu/JS/jquery.cookcodesmenu.js"></script>
 <!--Menu-->
<!--Floatbox-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="floatbox/floatbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="floatbox/floatbox.js"></script>
<!--Floatbox-->
<div id="logo"><img src="images/BodyLogo.jpg" width="25%" height="auto"   
alt="Logo"></div>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#menu').cookcodesmenu({
        //brand: 'jQueryScript'//
    });
});
</script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Parent 1
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Parent 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 8</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 9</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">item 10</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 6</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 7</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think that's the source of the problem. I think the problem lies with a piece of associated jquery I found:

```
(function ($, document, window) {
var
    // default settings object.
    defaults = {
        display: 1920, // From where mobile menu apears and desktop  menu gone
        //brand: '<a href="#"</a>', // Supports HTML//
        label: 'MENU', // Menu Label: // Supports HTML
        duplicate: true,
        duration: 200,
        easingOpen: 'swing',
        //fontFamily: 'Open Sans',//
        easingClose: 'swing',
        closedSymbol: "&#10133;", //Supports HTML
        openedSymbol: "&#10134;", //Supports HTML
        prependTo: 'body',
        appendTo: '',
        parentTag: 'a',
        closeOnClick: true,
        allowParentLinks: true,
        nestedParentLinks: true,
        showChildren: false,
        removeIds: true,
        removeClasses: false,
        removeStyles: false,
        animations: 'jquery',
        init: function () {},
        beforeOpen: function () {},
        beforeClose: function () {},
        afterOpen: function () {},
        afterClose: function () {}
    },
```

Origninally, I'd put a blank .html in the brand spot, but it was still taking up space in the html, shoving my logo out of position. As you see, I've tried to turn off "brand."  Now, where the brand label is supposed to go, it says "undefined," and my own logo is still shoved down below that. Hardly what I want.
It baffles me that a person writing a menu template would take it upon himself to dictate where the site logo must go, but that appears to be what he's done. Is there any way to work with this thing, or should I just try some other menu?

Comment: Kindly include the HTML so that I can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the wrong key, according to the documentation you have to use `brand` not `logo` to define your logo :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#menu').cookcodesmenu({
            brand: '<a href="/images/BodyLogo.jpg"></a>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Seems your anchor tag is not visible as logo because there is nothing
>   in side anchor tag.please try the below code push something in the
>   anchor tag.

```
<a href="https://google.com"><img src="yourpath/image.png"></a>
```

Please use something like this and try it.

```
 $(function() {
        $('#menu').cookcodesmenu({
            brand: '<a href="https://google.com"><img src="yourpath/image.png"></a>'
        });
    });
```